# What predates on cactus in the Atacama desert?

Tags: botany, ecology, plant-anatomy, predation, antipredator-adaptation

**Introduction**

Last week, I was in the [Atacama desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Desert) where I've seen many cacti. Some / many of them were seemingly suffering from predation. Most of predation seemed to be on [cardón](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echinopsis_atacamensis), often restricted (but not only) at the interface between the woody bottom part and the green spiny part. It looks like a big piece (maybe over 300 $\text{cm}^2$) of the flesh was bitten away. Unfortunately, I do not have a picture.

These cacti have very long spines and it was unclear to me what predator could maintain selection for cactus lineages to produce that many large spines.

In the desert, I have seen rabbits, guanacos, small birds, vultures, large black coleoptera and butterflies.

**Question**

In the Atacama region,

- What species predate on cacti?
- Is there a single species that causes most of the predation on cacti?

Comment: What does it look like? Are there pieces bitten/picked out, scratches?

Comment: In North America, [bighorn sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bighorn_sheep) are known to eat [*Ferocactus* sp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferocactus) (barrel cactus) by "pawing and butting at the cactus" (according to [Warrick and Krausman, 1989](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3671506?seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents)). Were there any animals around that could do that?

Comment: Guanacos probably! I just had a hard time to imagine so few guanacos making so much damage to so many cacti. Also it was surprising to me that guanacos could deal with those spines but I guess that if bighorn sheep can, why guanacos could not!

Comment: I agree with @Remi.b. I would just also note that I have seen similar damage on candelabra (Browningia sp.) in northern Chile, where an apparently similar-sized wound was effected by perching raptors (scarred by talons). I am pretty sure that one of them was a variable hawk and another a mountain caracara. Also, you likely saw vizcachas, not rabbits!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

This type of herbivory is probably from feral livestock, especially donkeys.

**Long Answer**

There is video footage of [guanacos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanaco) eating flowers off of cacti in the Atacama. For example, an image capture of a [Getty Images](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/video/guanaco-eats-a-cactus-flower-in-the-atacama-desert-stock-video-footage/3B2FBBD3_0223?uiloc=thumbnail_same_series_adp) video:

[image]

<sup>Credit: [BBC Natural History](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/search/filmmaker?filmmaker=BBC%20Natural%20History&family=creative&sort=best&license=rf,rr&page=1#license)</sup>

This type of [florivory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florivore) has been documented in related species of cacti as well (e.g., see [Gomes *et al.* (2016)](https://www.rufford.org/files/Plant%20Ecol,%20Sept,%202016.pdf)<sup>1</sup>)

However, I could find little evidence about guanacos eating the trunk of these cacti (especially to the degree you describe).

Actual [herbivory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbivore) of *Echinopsis* cacti has been reported in multiple publications. For example, [Peco *et al.* (2011)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/33861770/2011_Peco_et_al_Bark_damage_Cardones_JAE_75_981-985.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DEffects_of_bark_damage_by_feral_herbivor.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20190709%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190709T164102Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=2442d17cc865ede15fbff1ac987ebde5aa4b3ffb107c6b80b3eb88851aab49cd)<sup>2</sup> cite feral livestock as a major source of herbivory in columnar cacti in South America:

> Columnar cacti are an important feature of the arid “cardonal” landscape in South America. The predominant columnar cactus in the southern zone is *Echinopsis* (=*Trichocereus*) *terscheckii*. At some sites, the species **suffers considerable trunk damage, attributed in previous studies to feral livestock grazing (donkey and cattle)**.
>
> In a previous study we found that damage intensity on Echinopsis terscheckii trunks correlated with abundance of livestock dung in their surroundings, but not with the abundance of guanaco dung (*Lama guanicoe*) (Malo et al., 2011; Novillo and Ojeda, 2008). Futhermore, *E. terscheckii* was found in summer or winter donkey diet but not in guanaco diet in the study area (Reus pers. comm.). **Direct observation of donkeys feeding on columnar cacti suggests that this species is the main cause of stem damage**

See this [National geographic video](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2018/05/camels-cactus-mouth-papillae-animals/) explaining how camels and other related animals handle eating spiney cacti. (Specifically, they accomplish eating cacti through the use of hardened papillae guiding the spines down the throat vertically).

---

Works Cited:

1. <sup>Gomes, V.G.N., Koroiva, R. and Araujo, A.C., 2016. Vertebrate florivory on the short-columnar cactus Echinopsis rhodotricha K. Schum. in the Brazilian Chaco. Plant Ecology, 217(12), pp.1481-1487.</sup>
2. <sup>Peco, B., Borghi, C.E., Malo, J.E., Acebes, P., Almirón, M. and Campos, C.M., 2011. Effects of bark damage by feral herbivores on columnar cactus Echinopsis (= Trichocereus) terscheckii reproductive output. Journal of arid environments, 75(11), pp.981-985.</sup>